# PHP/JQuery Input Boxes for an image upload

Tags: php, jquery

I am currently working with multiple php image uploading but using this [SITE](http://dondedeportes.es/uploader-previewer/) I am unable to figure out, if I can increase from 3 to 4 inputs for file upload? i have looked through all the files but havent found anything relevant. Any one used this [SITE](http://dondedeportes.es/uploader-previewer/) example before can help me?

**Jquery**

```
(function($) {

$(document).ready(function() {

    // it must be checked if there are div.imageForms because the
    // uploaderPreviewer javascript may be not included and produce an error
    if ($('div.imageForms').length) {

        $('div.imageForms').append($.uploaderPreviewer.createImageForms());

        // the images are populated if the admin form is to edit, and not
        // to insert
        if ($('div.imageForms[images]').length) {
            var imageFilenames = $('div.imageForms[images]').attr('images').split(',');
            $.uploaderPreviewer.populateImages(imageFilenames);
            $('div.imageForms[images]').removeAttr('images');
        }
    }

    $('#buttonSave').click(function() {
        var itemId = $(this).attr('itemId');
        if (itemId) {
            $.itemForm.update(itemId);
        }
        else {
            $.itemForm.insert();
        }
    });

});

})(jQuery);

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<html>

<div class="imageForms"></div>

    <div class="buttonSave">
        <button id="buttonSave">Upload</button>
    </div>

</div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the DOM has loaded, you can manipulate the $.uploaderPreviewer object options. All you have to do is:

```
$.uploaderPreviewer.formsCount = 4;
```

See the revised code.

Comment: Thank you! this worked perfectly. Maybe your familiar with this. But Do you happen to know how to manipulate the position of the remove button?

Comment: Where do you want to move it to?